# void create and T create<T>

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6, linq-to-sql

Que diferencia hay entre usar void y T create

Void no me devuelve nada y T me devuelve una entidad, ¿el uso de ambos es deacuerdo al escenario que tengo, me conviene usar el uno o el otro?

Me traeria complicaciones trabajar mis metodos sin implementar el using

```
public void Create(T entity)
    {
        Context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
    }

    public void Update(T entity)
    {
        Context.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
        Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        TrySaveChanges();
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**>>¿el uso de ambos es deacuerdo al escenario que tengo, me conviene usar el uno o el otro?**

Depende de la finalidad de cada metodo, si se trata de

- Find() seria bastante raro definirlo como void, ya que se supone que busca y devuelve la lista de entidades
- Delete() podria no retornar nada, ya que solo tiene que eliminar

**>>Me traeria complicaciones trabajar mis metodos sin implementar el using**

No deberia traer problemas aunque la instancia del contexto de entity framework deberia ser por request, o sea cada transaccion deberia crear una nueva instancia

Si desarrollas un proyecto web la instancia la define el request al servidor. Si se trata de una desarrollo desktop cuando incias una transaccion genera la instancia del repositorio y se debe destruir cuando termina.